# How can I add custom error bars to a graph in Numbers

Tags: macos, numbers, software

[image: Screenshot]
I am using numbers 2014 - above is a screenshot that should explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double clicking on the error bars will let you change the values (as a formula).  I found that after a lot of rage clicking.

Comment: I mean **a lot** of rage clicking