# Adding standard deviation (custom) as error bar in Numbers v3.5.3

Tags: macos, numbers

Qn similar to [How can I add custom error bars to a graph in Numbers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155651/how-can-i-add-custom-error-bars-to-a-graph-in-numbers).
I'm not able to modify and/or customize error bars even after clicking on the graphical error bars for each series as mentioned in the other post. Yes, the positive, negative boxes do free up for entry and allow for range selection of standard deviation that I've calculated for my data, but once I select the range and click on the green check mark or press enter, the selection disappears and the positive, negative values go back to the default value [10]. Any way to fix this? Any known workaround?